# Difference between regexes

Tags: regex

Can someone explain the difference between the following regexes:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))*$
```

and

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(\.([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))*$`
```

Why cant we use a single group:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Instead of two shown above with alternation operator?

Comment: What are you testing it against?  What is your expected output versus what you're getting?

Comment: Put the regexes into something like https://www.debuggex.com/ and then you can easily see the difference between them.

Comment: @JonB this is for hostname matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make the difference more visible:

```
^
(
 [a-zA-Z0-9]|                              # Regex 1 only - matches 1 alnum character
 [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9] # Matches 2-63 characters
)
(
 \.
 (
  [a-zA-Z0-9]|                              # Regex 1 only
  [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]
 )
)*
$
```

With the alternation,

```
a.a
```

matches.

Without it, it doesn't because at least two letters/digits are required before and after the dot.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted the first regexp allows a single character before the dot.  The second regexp requires two.

To avoid the alternation while retaining semantic you would need to rewrite the first part to something like:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?
```

That is you would need to make the `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]` optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])
  ^         |                       ^
  |         -----------------|      |
Allows exactly one character or atleast two characters.
```

Without the first `[a-zA-Z0-9]`(part before `|` ), it won't allow a single character.